# Como pegar um elemento filho especifico no CSS, sendo que eles tem a mesma classe?

Tags: css3

Quero por uma cor de background somente na div 3, como eu faria pra pegar ela em especifico no CSS ?

```html
<section id="color-palette">
  <div class="color">1 </div>
  <div class="color">2 </div>
  <div class="color">3 </div>
  <div class="color">4 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Você pode usar [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa é utilizar a pseudo-classe [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) que seleciona a um ou mais elementos com base em sua posição entre irmãos do mesmo tipo.

Use em conjunto do [combinador descendente](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)(um caractere de espaço simples) para restringir os elementos selecionados a um determinado ancestral.

```css
.color-box {
  background-color: seashell;
  width: 50px margin: auto;
}

.color {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*Seleciona apenas .color que seja descendente de .color-box*/

.color-box .color:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color-box .color:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.color-box .color:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="color-box">
  <div class="color">1</div>
  <div class="color">2</div>
  <div class="color">3</div>
</section>
<!--Nenhum dos elementos abaixo terão o estilo afetado-->
<section class="NOcolor-box">
  <div class="color">1</div>
  <div class="color">2</div>
  <div class="color">3</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `nth-child()` para selecionar um elemento no index desejado.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```css
.color-box {
  background-color: seashell;
  width: 50px
  margin: auto;
}

.color {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 30px auto;
 height: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.color:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.color:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="color-box">
  <div class="color">1</div>
  <div class="color">2</div>
  <div class="color">3</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Vlwww =) deu bom aqui ! Muito obrigado a todos<3